# Sphinx only returning 2 (out of) 8 fields using Sphinx PHP API

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine, sphinx

**I Can't answer my own question yet, so here is the answer**

I'm an idiot... didn't reindex every time.

```
searchd --stop
indexer --all
searchd
```

Problem solved. Sorry for wasting anyone's time :( Hope this helps someone.

** End of answer **

I have a PHP model running a Query against an indexed table (call it SONGS).

The query in the sphinx.conf is as follows:

```
sql_query       = \
    SELECT \
    songs.id AS song_id, \
    songs.title AS song_title, \
    songs.upload_stamp AS song_published, \
    songs.uri AS song_uri, \
    songs.artist_id, \
    songs.song_rank, \
    songs.vote_count \
    FROM songs
```

However, when i run the code to execute the query, the resulting array only contains the 2 fields song_published & artist_id, and is missing the other 6 fields.

The php code looks as follows:

```
$this->cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$this->cl->SetConnectTimeout ( 1 );
$this->cl->SetArrayResult ( true );
$this->cl->SetWeights ( array ( 100, 1 ) );

$result = $this->cl->Query($this->search_term,'song-index');
```

I've tried a multitude of things, and restarted searchd (**edit** and reindexed) each time to no avail.. it is returning the correct results, but only 2 of the 8 fields in the resulting array.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated!!!!

**EDIT...**

Here are the declarations for the values as well

```
sql_attr_uint       = artist_id
sql_attr_uint       = song_id
sql_attr_uint       = vote_count
sql_attr_timestamp  = song_published
sql_attr_float      = song_rank
sql_attr_string     = song_uri
sql_attr_string     = song_title
```

Comment: Just to be sure, did you reindex? because searchd only searches the index but you need to run indexer to rebuild the index

Comment: Yep, thank you! Did stop/reindex every time I made a .conf change.

**EDIT** I am an idiot. No I didn't re-index the last few (important) changes. Sorry... and thank you!

Comment: NP it happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot... didn't reindex every time.

searchd --stop
indexer --all
searchd
Problem solved. Sorry for wasting anyone's time :( Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the following to create new indexes after config changes without stopping searchd.  it'll rotate in the new index after is is finished generating and then delete the old one.

```
indexer --rotate --all
```

see the [indexer cml reference](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.1.html#ref-indexer) for more details.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is correct and is actually the preferred method, is it not? Upvoted.